# DNS Setup - Complex Setup - Need Ideas

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, bind

I have a very weird situation here. I have a Sonicwall VPN firewall, i can only use L2tp vpn for each Windows 2008 r2 Client using the windows built in vpn. Why? The Sonicwall GlobalVPN Client does NOT work for windows 2008 R2 =\ SSLVPN is out of the question b/c it will not stay connected if logged off.

SO,

I can communicate with all clients, even a Site-To-Site VPN i have attached to the Sonicwall and the clients can ping that remote site.

The ISSUE =)

IF i want to ping a specific IP / Machine to the Site-To-Site from the client I can BECAUSE the ip is static all the time. The client thou, NOT. It will grab an IP from the Sonicwall on every re-connect. (Built in script i made)

UNLESS i create an internal DNS behind the Sonicwall so every time the Clients connect it pushes the new IP / Host-name and the Servers on the Site-To-Site side can ping the clients just fine via host-name / FQDN. This would mean i need to create an AD and the clients have to be connected to it. Correct?

Well, 1 idea i had was to hack it up. I am able to ssh into the FW and do a show user status. This display the client name and IP it received from DHCP, then push that information to a small dns behind the sonicwall. Thoughts? Maybe a linux based DNS server?

I am sorry in advance if this is not the proper way of requesting help but honestly Sonicwall / Dell is NO help at all.

thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?

Comment: Any time you need to implement a "Complex Setup", you should pause and think about how you can turn it into a simple setup. This is overly complicated and will result in a nightmare.

Comment: I agree, i guess is there a better way to setup a VPN Star Topo using this sonicwall, Windows 2008 R2, and make sure that another Site-To-Site VPN is able to connect across to each Windows 2008 Client?